# Bezier curve between faces of different meshes

Tags: animation-nodes

Help me please to set up nodes, so that curve will be instanced between every two faces of different meshes.

1. Faces should be selected by index, like 1-1, 2-2, etc.
2. Curve should be directed along faces' normals.

I've replicated something partly similiar to my needs from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41980/29200) answer, but it is limited to only 2 faces inside one object.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop over both the polygon centers and polygon normals of both mesh and create some between each two centers using the normals as handles:

[image: Node Tree]

Or by using the Instancer node:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you very much! But can it be done using Instancer, rather than one object with many curves?

Comment: @SergeL Edited the answer.